# Make a user write a sentence and send it to a file vertically

Tags: python

I want to make a program that prints a sentence written by the user, and print it into a file vertically. My current code is:

```
# Create a program that takes sentence from user, and splits 
# the words into a list.
# Then write the list into a a file vertically.

# Take sentence from user
sentence = raw_input('Write a sentence :')

# Split the words of sentence
splited = str(sentence.split())
print splited

# Write to file
f=open('C:\Users\QamarAli\Desktop\HelloFile.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(splited)):
    f.writelines(splited)
    f.writelines("\n")
f.close()
```

If I input the sentence `Hi i am aFAFAF`, then then contents of the text file are:

```
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
[u'Hi', u'i', u'am', u'aFAFAF']
```

Whereas I want it to be

```
Hi
i
am 
aFAFAF
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? If I run it, I get the error `TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` from line 23 (the start of the `for` loop).

Comment: Yes this is the exact same code

Comment: No it can't be - the code you pasted doesn't run, whereas you claim to get some output. I think where you had `for i in range(len()):` it should have been `for i in range(len(splited)):`. I've cleaned it up the best I can.

Comment: Thanks I dont know what you are talking about but my new code is much better  :)

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as

```
f.write('\n'.join(sentence.split()))
```

No need to even create the `splited` variable (you could even eliminate the `sentence` variable if you wanted to: `f.write('\n'.join(raw_input().split()))`).

---

If you wanted to persist with the `for` loop, you probably meant to do something like this:

```
splited = sentence.split()  # notice no `str`

for i in range(len(splited)):
    f.write(splited[i])
    f.write('\n')
```

Or more simply:

```
for s in sentence.split():
    f.write(s + '\n')
```

Note that this approach will always leave a trailing newline character whereas `f.write('\n'.join(sentence.split()))` will not. You can easily add this extra newline character if you needed by using

```
f.write('\n'.join(sentence.split()) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are 'printing' the list to a file, while you should loop through the list.

```
     # your code. get rid of your own for loop and replace it with this one
     for part in splited:
            #this is the part which I am talking about
            f.writelines(part)
            f.writelines("\n")
     # your code
```

Comment: i WOULD LIKE YOUR COMMENT BUT I NEED 1 MORE REPUTATION TO LIKE IT, I NEED 15, I HAVE 14 AND YES I WILL REMOVE THE NOOB. THANKS ALOT

Comment: But when i get the final product, it has all wierd u's like this:[
u
'
H
i
'
,
 
u
'
i
'
,
 
u
'
a
m
'
,
 
u
'
a
F
A
F
A
F
'
]    (But its vertical)

Comment: @Afaq it's because you are converting the whole list into one string using str(s.split()), see my post, has some explanations.

Comment: Ah, got it. You shouldn't say str(sentence.split), because you're making a string representation of your list and that is not what you want. You can just use splited = sentence.split()

Answer (score 2):

OK, instead of giving code golf style answers, I'll explain the mistakes if you prefer!

`splited = str(sentence.split())`

You shouldn't convert all that to a string, split() returns a `list`, so keep it as a list of words :

`words = sentence.split()`

Next, your loop is wrong :

`for i in range(len()):`

You were going for `for i in range(len(words))`, but you can just do `for word in words:`

---

So you could try:

```
for word in sentence.split():
   f.write(word + '\n')
```